# Opening a HTML file from my computer in web browser

Tags: python, html, os.path, python-webbrowser

I would like to open a HTML file that is stored in my computer on a web browser but I'm getting an error (see below).

```
from urllib import urlopen
from webbrowser import open as webopen
from os import getcwd
from os.path import normpath
```

I have this code:

```
def open_html_file():
    path = normpath.abspath('New_News.html')
    url = 'file://' + path

    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(html)
    webopen.open(url)
```

and I'm getting this error when the code is run:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'abspath'
```

Comment: `os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath('New_News.html'))`

Answer (score 0):

`normpath` is a function, and doesn't have a `abspath` attribute.
I think you meant to do that:

```
from os.path import abspath

path = abspath('New_News.html')
```